# Are superhero masks effective at concealing your identity?

Tags: perception

In modern comic book fiction, a superhero wears a partial mask to obscure their identity.  This mask is properly known as a "Domino Mask"
[image]

Now obviously these masks are not the most effective masks in the world.  However, is there any cog sci evidence that they provide any protection at all?  I highly doubt there's any evidence to show they prevent someone from identifying you, but is there any evidence to suggest they even slow identification down or increase errors?

Comment: Here's a Gizmodo piece about fooling facial recognition: http://io9.gizmodo.com/how-fashion-can-be-used-to-thwart-facial-recognition-te-1495648863 . It's kind of relevant and might be an interesting read for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any proper identity recognition experiments using such a mask, and obviously it depends on how difficult the recognition test is. However, [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010027712001412) is a paper where they found that sunglasses (and facemasks) impeded accuracy in an *emotion* recognition task. I would guess that often identity recognition is just as difficult as emotion recognition, so I would assume glasses or a mask would make people (slightly) worse. In general, this is a question about what features are necessary/useful for face recognition. There is lots of research about this, and studies such as [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Frederic_Gosselin2/publication/11169253_Show_Me_the_Features!_Understanding_Recognition_From_the_Use_of_Visual_Information/links/55e8808308aeb65162630c88.pdf) show that the eyes are particularly important. So disrupting this part of the face, and potentially the relationships between them, is actually not a bad way to disguise yourself (though obviously a full-on balaclava would be better!).

Answer (score 0):

> *However, is there any cog sci evidence that they provide any protection at all? I highly doubt there's any evidence to show they prevent someone from identifying you, but is there any evidence to suggest they even slow identification down or increase errors?*

No and yes. As far as I know there's no evidence that **masks** in particular provide a special protection that differs from other physical objects that disrupt the face/bodyparts like when you cover your face with your own hands.

However I think it is helpful to explain (concisely) how identification and visual recognition in the process of perceptual organization works:

**Stage 1**
When we see something in our environment (face of a person) our organ of perception (eyes in this case) receives a stimulus (light) that causes the creation of an neural impulse that is send to the brain (image of a face).

**Stage 2**
Now our brain combines the information (the image of the face that we just saw) with a-priori-knowledge from our brain (a cocktail of experiences, expectations, language knowledge...). By doing so it identifies the object (face of my friend) **and** recognizes it. Recognizing means you are aware of the object's function (it's a friend, not a foe -> no danger).

**Stage 3**
The result is a mental re-creation of the object we just saw – a so called *percept*.

So to sum it up, if a mask or any other physical object is in the line of sight, it alters the information we receive about the covered object. And if our brain cannot *fill in the blanks*, the stage of identification is slowed down or the object cannot be identified at all.
So it depends on what part of the face is covered and to what extend *and* how much information about the object we try to identify is already available in our brains.